# The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) E, int

Tags: java, arraylist

I had a previous error that wanted the left hand side of an assignment to be  a variable. So this time I rewrote it to get and set the value at k, but then I get the operator is undefined for argument types.

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> ArrayList<E> insertionSort (ArrayList<E> list)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        E elements = list.get(i);
        int k;

        for (k = i - 1; k >= 0 && list.get(k).compareTo(elements) > 0; k--)
            list.set(k, list.get(k) + 1); //Error here

        list.set(k, list.get(k) + 1) = elements; //Error here
    }

    for (int k = 0; k <= list.size(); k++)
        System.out.println(list.get(k) + "\t");

    return list;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `list.get(k) + 1` to do? Did you perhaps mean `list.get(k + 1)`? And what did you expect the effect of `list.set(...) = elements;` to be? That's just invalid...

Comment: (Basically, it's hard to help you when we don't know what you're trying to do. We can explain what's wrong with the code you've got, but not what the correct code is.)

Comment: Oh wait I see what I did. When I had the previous error I had it list.get(k+1) = list.get(k). My mistake.

Comment: You can always use Iterator!

Comment: I also forgot to switch the next line with elements = list.get(k+1) Thank you and I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ArrayList doesn't necessarily contain a numeric type, so you can't add 1 to the value of list.get(k).

If you meant to get the next *index* then you need list.get(k+1)